# SELinux : Where I find selinux policy for google-chrome on Fedora Linux?

Tags: selinux, google-chrome

How do I find all the SELinux policies used for Google Chrome on Fedora Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for file contexts? A simple `grep` ought to find them.

```
grep -e chrome -e chromium /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts*
```

If you need policy sources from which policies were built, you can find those in [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/fedora-selinux/selinux-policy/search?q=chrome) or by getting the corresponding SRPM for your installed package.